# Report trigger for Ubuntu Report restarts and ends with crash

Tags: 18.04, crash

I have a machine that runs a cryptomining software gpu overnight and nonstop. Sometimes it triggers ubuntu report multiple times until it crashes. It starts by creating user slice of root then stars report triggering:

```
Mar 24 01:27:35 r9 systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of root.
Mar 24 01:27:35 r9 systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 0...
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[13968]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[13968]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[13968]: Starting D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[13968]: Listening on GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[13968]: Started Pending report trigger for Ubuntu Report.
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[13968]: Reached target Paths.
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[13968]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[13968]: Listening on REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[13968]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[13968]: Reached target Timers.
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[13968]: Listening on D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[13968]: Reached target Sockets.
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[13968]: Reached target Basic System.
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 0.
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[13968]: Reached target Default.
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[13968]: Startup finished in 35ms.
```

Then it closes it:

```
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 0...
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[13968]: Stopped target Default.
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[13968]: Stopped target Basic System.
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[13968]: Stopped target Timers.
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[13968]: Stopped target Paths.
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[13968]: Stopped Pending report trigger for Ubuntu Report.
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[13968]: Stopped target Sockets.
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[13968]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[13968]: Closed D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[13968]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[13968]: Closed GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[13968]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[13968]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[13968]: Closed REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[13968]: Reached target Shutdown.
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[13968]: Starting Exit the Session...
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[13968]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 13986 (kill).
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 0.
Mar 24 01:27:36 r9 systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of root.
```

It repeats continuously until the system crashes because of memory problem:

```
"echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message"
```

Could anyone tell what "report trigger for ubuntu report" is? Why does it start and stop repeatedly?

I am using ubuntu 18.04 and kernel 5.4.0-54-generic.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Report (https://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-report) is a service that:

> This tool will collect and report metrics from current hardware, partition and session information. This information can't be used to identify a single machine and is presented before being sent to the server.

It runs at every boot. Your output seems to show normal behavior.

Your output does not seem to show it "*start and stop repeatedly*" during a single boot cycle. If it did, that would be a bug.

---

Note that this tool is **100% open source**. You can audit the code to see what it does. You can easily view the reports that get sent (try it: `ubuntu-report show` or see `man ubuntu-report`. There's no secret here, and there's no personal information here.

Comment: I dont want to copy paste the whole rep since it would waste of space. The thing is this doesn't behave consistently. If this is a bug, should i change the kernel or what?

Comment: Oh, you seem to have asked an [XY question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Instead of asking about how to troubleshoot your crashes, you have jumped to the (unlikely) conclusion that ubuntu-report --which is tiny, consumes almost no resources, does not run as root, and is self-terminating-- must be the culprit. Advice: Open a new question showing your complete troubleshooting data. Include any .crash reports in /var/crash

Comment: I still want to troubleshoot why ubuntu report is restarting. Do you think I should start from crash report?

Comment: If there is a .crash report corresponding to one of those events, that's usually the *best* place to start.

Answer (score 0):

The crash causes by flushing data to disk takes too long and causing "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" error. The ubuntu reporting is nothing to do with it

fixed it by setting the following variables

vm.dirty_background_ratio
vm.dirty_ratio